# Is it safe to reuse TextEncoder over and over again to measure string size?

Tags: javascript

So, a little bit of context : I have a huge CSV file (tens of millions of lines, ~17GB) that I'd like to send bit by bit. CSV file will contain non english alphabet like cyrillic and maybe some japanese characters (encoding UTF-8). lets say the chunk size is 10MB, then I want to parse row by row (not byte by byte), keep appending every parsed row to string, and once the string's byte size is at least 10MB, send the rows as chunk out to server, and then onto the next rows until all is sent. normally, you'd slice by byte, meaning, you may slice in the middle of the row. I need to keep the rows intact because server will immediately process sent rows.

I know we can use

> new Blob([str]).size

or

> new TextEncoder().encode(str).length

Here is a pseudocode (since I'm still browsing what csv parser I want to use):

```
while(!eof(mycsv.csv)){
   aggregatedRows += mycsv.nextRow();
   //check current size of aggregatedRows -> TextEncoder or new Blob???
   if(aggregatedRows > 10MB) sendToServer();
}
```

I tested `TextEncoder` which is faster than `Blob`, but for `Blob`, since it's immutable, I need to keep spamming `new Blob()`. So, my question is, do I also need to spam `new TextEncoder()` or can it be reused?
Or is there a better way to achieve this in 2023? If possible, I want vanilla javascript without extra libraries.

Thanks

Comment: TextEncoder? How are you using it? This doesn't do the same thing than Blob.slice() at all. And yes we now have streaming interfaces, but once again what you do is very unclear.

Comment: I'm parsing CSV row by row, and hold in some string, or whatever. once the string "byte size" has become >= x bytes, I send the string out. basically, this is file splitting, but not by bytes, but by rows. and since I need to measure if the current string is of x bytes, I use either `new Blob` or `TextEncoder`.

Comment: @Kaiido I added a snippet to make this easier to understand. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I see better the idea now. At this rate you'll be halfway of having done the whole parsing on your own. Determining the line break is one of the most complicated tasks in csv parsing. (`a,b,"[CR LF]"d` should still be a single row.) The best is probably to find a parser that does accepts streams as input directly. I personally use PapaParse on the front-end, which can stream from a File, and while I never used it like that, [their Github page](https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse/#papa-parse-for-node) says they do support ReadableStreams in node directly, so you can pipe your data directly.

Comment: And you mention Cyrillic and Japanese characters, are we to assume you already know how to read these correctly? The main issue you might face is chunking your original Blob between two codepoints of the same character.

Comment: @Kaiido what do you mean? cause I'm chunking per row. Not sure how codepoint might be an issue here. adn yes, so far, I see that papa parse is the best option for now

Comment: Before you're able to slice it per row, you must read your `Blob` per chunks (you won't be able to create a string that's more than 512MB in V8). You have no idea where the next new line will be, so, to do this initial read, you are forced to slice based on bytes position. This slicing may very well end between two code points of the same character, thus breaking said character. You'd need a stream decoder to avoid that situation. But once again, feeding the whole file to your parser and let it do its job from the beginning is probably your best option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your original question: Yes, you can safely reuse `TextEncoder`, since it only provides access to the `encode` function: it will receive an string, and return a *new* `Uint8Array` (it won't hold information of your data).

Now on what you want to accomplish (make it faster): I suppose that you have a loop that reads the original file, join strings line by line, and then checks the length of the accumulated string to decide where to stop and send the next chunk.

If it is so, then you can make it faster:

- Before the loop: Create two variables: an empty array (`myArray`), and a numeric one set to 0 `totalLength`.
- Inside the loop: Instead of joining the string you read on each loop, you can push it in `myArray` (this means lest string allocations)
- Measure the current string (not the whole array!) and add the value to `totalLength`.
- If `totalLength` > 10MB exit the loop
- After the loop: create the final string by calling on `myArray.join('')`.

Comment: Yes! correct. so, I parse row by row in a loop, populate the string and measure the string every iteration. if the string size is >= x bytes, ship it out.